# Type error using snaplet-session

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

The App type

```
data App = App
    { _heist       :: Snaplet (Heist App)
    , _session     :: Snaplet SessionManager
    }
```

The initializer

```
...
addRoutes [ ("/ss", companyHandler)
          , ("", heistServe)
          ]
...
```

The handler

```
companyHandler :: Handler b v ()
companyHandler = method GET getter <|> method POST setter
  where
    getter = do
        value <- getFromSession "name"
        writeText $ fromMaybe "nothing" value
    setter = do
        mname <- getParam "name"
        setInSession "name" (convert mname)
        getter
    convert = T.pack . B.unpack . (fromMaybe "nothing")
```

The `heistServe` has type `Handler b (Heist b) ()`

Type error:

```
src/Tutorial.hs:50:52:
    Couldn't match type `v' with `SessionManager'
      `v' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for companyHandler :: Handler b v ()
          at src/Tutorial.hs:50:1
    Expected type: Handler b v ()
       Actual type: Handler b SessionManager ()
    In the second argument of `method', namely `setter'
    In the second argument of `(<|>)', namely `method POST setter'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind your `SessionManager` to the context of the handler before you can use functions that operate on it. This is done with:

```
withTop session $ setInSession "name" (convert mname)
-- Where session is the generated lens for your snaplet
```

If you also want to commit your session afterwards (because you altered the session and didn't just read a variable), you need to:

```
withSession . withTop session $ ...
```

If you add the following piece of code to your main application's snaplet initialization code, you don't have to worry about committing sessions at all, because it is done automatically for you:

```
wrapHandlers withSession
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `withSession session $ setInSession "name" (convert mname) :: Handler b SessionManager ()`, for `setInSession :: Text -> Text -> Handler b SessionManager ()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't test the code, which I should have done. It seems that the session API is constructed in a weird way; you need to use `withTop` instead of `withSession`. If you do `withSession . withTop session $ ...`, what it will do for you is to commit the session after you're done with it.

Comment: It compiles, but session is not shared between requests. The full code is [here using with](https://gist.github.com/1471406/547b13d5603a12090df2d2ad3fb7fd124ce3619e) and [here using withSession and withTop](https://gist.github.com/1471406/082e20e0a217255d52d79a770bc3ebdf554d578c)

Comment: The issue isn't with the session management system, but with the way you test this. See [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489779/230461).

Comment: Thanks, it works now. The last question is what `commit session` do? I found no difference using and not using it.

Comment: It is useful for when you write a back end that needs to commit its changes, for example a database. The default back end uses cookies, but this is not always what you want (because if you store a lot of session data, the cookie grows to be very large).
By the way, don't forget to accept a solution so that others with the same question can profit from it!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is with the following line:

```
companyHandler = with session $ method GET getter <|> method POST setter
```

Another thing I find helpful is to specialize the type signatures to my application.  In this case, the new type signature would be:

```
companyHandler :: Handler App App ()
```

Most of the time you won't be writing generic code that should be reusable across multiple apps, so the small loss of generality here doesn't hurt you.  Having more concrete type signatures generally makes error messages easier to decipher, which can be a big help in getting your code compiling.  Even when I am writing code that should be generic across all apps/snaplets, sometimes I still find it helpful to start with a more specific type and then generalize after I get it working.

What dflemstr said about withSession is correct.  I typically prefer to do withSession once around everything as opposed to putting it on the call to setInSession, but you should do whatever is appropriate for your application.