# Session is not shared between requests using Snaplet.Session

Tags: session, haskell, haskell-snap-framework

A simple example of Snaplet and Session [here](https://gist.github.com/1471406)

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/sessioin -d "key=k&value=v"
k
getter

$ curl http://localhost:8000/sessioin

getter
```

I cannot get session in the 2nd request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your definition of `with`, you probably forgot to commit your session after you set values in it.

Also, you're using `curl` to test this system. `curl` doesn't preserve cookies by default, which is why your session cookie is lost. Try using this (works on my machine):

```
curl -c cookies.txt http://localhost:8000/session -d "key=k&value=v"
curl -b cookies.txt http://localhost:8000/session
```

See also the revised answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475088/type-error-using-snaplet-session/8476390#8476390).

Comment: It makes no difference if I commit the session

Comment: I found the issue, so that it at least works on my machine. See the updated answer for more info.